# Downloading files using fopen(),fread(),feof()... Downloaded files are broken

Tags: php

I have a script that download's files from a server, all works nice. But when the file is downloaded either it's a jpg or png file. I cant seem to open it with any program to view it. (windows photo gallery or fireworks)

When i download a video file (avi). I cant open it with windows media player, but i can open it with vlc media player.

I always get a error msg, cant read file or file broken.

Here is the code, is it reliable or should i consider using fsocketopen or curl maybe.

I have tried altering the headers looking for more answers on the web, with no luck.

Anyone have an idea to whats wrong?

```
chmod("extensions_img/test.jpg",0755);

$fullPath = "http://www.website_url.com/extensions_img/test.jpg";

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {

    $fsize = filesize("extensions_img/test.jpg");

    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    switch($ext) {

        case "pdf":
            $ctype = "application/pdf";
            break;
        case "exe":
            $ctype = "application/octet-stream";
            break;
        case "zip":
            $ctype = "application/zip";
            break;
        case "doc":
            $ctype = "application/msword";
            break;
        case "xls":
            $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case "ppt":
            $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
            break;
        case "gif":
            $ctype = "image/gif";
            break;
        case "png":
            $ctype = "image/png";
            break;
        case "jpeg":
            $ctype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case "jpg":
            $ctype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case "mp3":
            $ctype = "audio/mp3";
            break;
        case "wav":
            $ctype = "audio/x-wav";
            break;
        case "wma":
            $ctype = "audio/x-wav";
            break;
        case "mpeg":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mpg":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mpe":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mov":
            $ctype = "video/quicktime";
            break;
        case "avi":
            $ctype = "video/x-msvideo";
            break;
        case "src":
            $ctype = "plain/text";
            break;
        default:
            $ctype = "application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public");

    header("Expires: 0");

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    header("Cache-Control: private",false);

    header("Content-type: " . $ctype);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: public"); //use this to open files directly

    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 4096);
    flush();
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
```

Comment: Try doing it with a text file and then looking a the cntents of the file. It could be that there are PHP error messages getting output to the buffer, so they are trashing the file.

Comment: `$fsize` is always `0`, because the file does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
while(!feof($fd)) {
    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    flush();
}
```

You aren't echoing anything so probably your file is empty?

Comment: thx samura that fixed the problem completely=)...i tried using while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 4096);
  echo $buffer;
  flush();
    } but your method... LIFESAVER been dealing with this problem forever. thx....and btw donno what happend to the minus 1, maybe i acc. hit it sry.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `Content-length:` header containing a filesize you obtained incorrectly.

```
// You are opening a remote file:
$fullPath = "http://www.website_url.com/extensions_img/test.jpg";

// You are retrieving the filesize of a local file that may or may not exist
$fsize = filesize("extensions_img/test.jpg");
```

So, most likely, your `Content-length` really looks like the following:

```
 header("Content-length: 0");
```

...unless you have an actual local file of the same name, then you'll be supplying its filesize rather than the intended remote file.

According to [`filesize()` documentation](http://us.php.net/filesize), some URL wrappers are supported. You might try to retrieve the filesize from the remote file:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine
>   which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

```
$fsize = filesize($fullpath);
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I originally set the $fsize = filesize($fullpath); but it throws me the following error (Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://www.website_url/extensions_img/test.jpg). But if I keep the $fsize = filesize("extensions_img/test.jpg"); I notice the full size of the file gets downloaded.

Comment: @MortenHøgseth If you can't obtain the filesize over http, you would have to download the file and save locally before streaming it to the client, I believe. Does it work if you just omit the `Content-length` header?

Comment: You might be able to use cURL to get a content-length from the server supplying it.

Comment: A closer look tells me that only the half file size is downloaded. With the Content-length header and without it. I also dow. a php file, i noticed when i opened it that from about line 15 and down, the text was cut and removed. But thx for the reply, i will see if i can debugg my way to find whats wrong with the files. Will come back and post when I find out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`filesize($url)`](http://php.net/filesize) will download the file twice. And no idea why you are using `fopen/fread` anyway, when there is [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or `fpassthru`:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$size = strlen($data);
$mime = current(preg_grep('/^Content-Type:/i', $http_response_header));
```

Please note how this also gets you the correct MIME type (just pass along the whole stirng via `header` for simplicity). Or even all the headers.

Comment: thx for the reply, i will read up on file_get_contents and fpassthru function.

Comment: file_get_contents is not a good idea in this case, a) it will read the entire file into memory and b) the user can't start downloading the file until the server has read in the entire file (memory inefficient and slow)